# How to catch errors with loggers like Bunyan?

Tags: node.js, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm running a NodeJS script inside a Docker container, which is inside a Container-optimized OS inside a Google Compute Instance.

Simple `console.log()` doesn't reach Google Cloud Logger. Thus I'm using `bunyan` library.

However, I have two problems:

1. Some libraries I use just write logs to `stdout` and I have no way to see them, except by SSHing into the GCE instance and poking around there.
2. I'm a human being and can mess up with threading or something. In this case an error may occur that also will not show up in Cloud Logger.

So, the question is: how do I make NodeJS send `stdout` and `stderr` logs to the Cloud Logger?

Here is an example:

```js
import { createLogger } from 'bunyan'
const { LoggingBunyan } = require('@google-cloud/logging-bunyan')
import sourceMap from 'source-map-support'
sourceMap.install()

function startLogger () {
  let streams: any[] = []
  if (process.env.__DEV__) {
    streams.push({ stream: process.stdout, level: 'debug' })
  } else {
    const loggingBunyan = new LoggingBunyan()
    streams.push(loggingBunyan.stream('debug'))
  }
  return createLogger({ name: 'my-script', streams })
}

const logger = startLogger()
process.on('unhandledRejection', logger.error)

const start = async () => {
  logger.info(`hello`)
  try {
    logger.info(`start`)

    setTimeout(() => {
      throw Error('error from timeout') // <= this must be caught by bunyan and sent to Clodu Logger
    }, 1000)

    sleep(5000)

    logger.info(`finish`)
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('crash:', e)
  }
}

start()

function sleep (time: number) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}
```

By this (probably excessive) example, I'm trying to show an accidental unhandled error. I know I  can put try-catch in the `setTimout` callback. It's just an example.

Comment: As per the [git](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-bunyan) Cloud Logging is compatible with Bunyan. is it related?

Comment: @Mahboob yes, it's already integrated as per the docs you've referred to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not let your server to crash:

```js
process.setUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback(logger.error);
process.on('unhandledRejection', e => logger.error(e));
```